# NDSolve saying "encountered non-numerical value at t==0.`

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I wrote this code with the target of tracing the motion of a particle using ParametricPlot:
[image: The code for NDSolve]

[image: Values of the variables mentioned in the equations]

I have tried solving the equations on paper as well, but I do not understand where the Error is coming from. All the values are numerical, there are no non-numerical values. 
Kindly help me figure this out. Please pardon me for providing pics of the code as I couldn't copy them using LaTex. 
Thanks

Comment: Please, do not post images, but the code. I suggst you follow the tour or read the help to edit your question including codes...

Comment: My apologies. I'll update the question in 5 hours.

Comment: See what `Simplify[{eq1,eq2,eq3}/.t->0,{xin,yin,zin,xdin,ydin,zdin}]` looks like (i.e. apply the initial conditions, and check to see if that gives equations for the second derivatives that are entirely numerical). I'd guess it is related to the `Sum` terms.

Comment: Also why are you specifying `Shooting` as the NDSolve method here? You shouldn't need to.

Comment: I was trying to follow some suggestions on related questions which is why I added that even though it does not rectify the error.... I will remove that

Comment: @KraZug, when I used the simplify command, the code kept compiling and and hasn't finished even after 30 minutes.

Comment: After 40 minutes, I have got these results:
${x''[0] == 1.33515 * 10^{-20} [-8.79993 * 10^{-11}],
y''[0] == 1.33515 * 10^{-20} [-1.20956 * 10^{-10}],
z''[0] == 1.33515 * 10^{-20} [20768.8]}$

Comment: With square brackets? If so, that is definitely wrong. It should just be a numerical value on the right hand side.

Comment: I should probably have suggested `{eq1,eq2,eq3}/.t->0/.({xin,yin,zin,xdin,ydin,zdin}/.Equal->Rule)`, without the Simplify.
The Sum is likely to be the issue. The actual code may well make it more obvious.

Comment: ${eq1,eq2,eq3}/.t->0/.({xin,yin,zin,xdin,ydin,zdin}/.Equal->R‌​ule)$ is giving error, "ReplaceAll: ..... neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."
Also, can you please what do you mean when you say "The Sum is likely to be the issue"?\

Comment: You need to provide the code, not as images. Although actually, it looks like you have a square bracket instead of a round bracket in your definitions, after `e/mi` in all three cases. If you fix that it should work.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!
And I'll keep in mind to type the questions completely in the future.